# how to use remove_widget?

Tags: python, kivy

i tried to make a simple program but i have problems with remove_widget. Also i checked many posts and sites but i couldn't find answer

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder

class FirstScr(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        main_line = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', padding=8, spacing=8)
        go = Label(text='Нажми на нужную кнопку!', halign='center')
        self.btn = Button(text='Жми!', size_hint=(.3,.2), pos_hint={'center_x':.5})
        self.btn2 = Button(text='Не жми сюда!', size_hint=(.3,.2), pos_hint={'center_x':.5})

        main_line.add_widget(go)
        main_line.add_widget(self.btn)
        main_line.add_widget(self.btn2)

        self.add_widget(main_line)

        self.btn.on_press = self.next
        self.btn2.on_press = self.next2
    def next(self):
        main_line = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', padding=8, spacing=8)
        go2 = Label(text='Молодец!')

        main_line.add_widget(go2)
        
        self.add_widget(main_line)
    def next2(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.remove_widget(self.btn2)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(FirstScr(name='first'))

        return sm
MyApp().run()
```

Can u help me guys?

I tried to change location of function but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like next2 calls super for no reason before removing the widget.

if your aim is to remove btn2 you should remove it from the layout :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder

class FirstScr(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        main_line = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=8, spacing=8)
        go = Label(text='Click the necessary button!', halign='center')
        self.btn = Button(text='Press!', size_hint=(.3, .2), pos_hint={'center_x': .5})
        self.btn2 = Button(text="Don't press here!", size_hint=(.3, .2), pos_hint={'center_x': .5})

        main_line.add_widget(go)
        main_line.add_widget(self.btn)
        main_line.add_widget(self.btn2)

        self.add_widget(main_line)

        self.btn.on_press = self.next
        self.btn2.on_press = self.next2

    def next(self):
        main_line = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=8, spacing=8)
        go2 = Label(text='Well done!')

        main_line.add_widget(go2)

        self.add_widget(main_line)

    def next2(self):
        # Remove btn2 from the layout (main_line)
        self.main_line.remove_widget(self.btn2)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(FirstScr(name='first'))

        return sm

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: so ur answer didn't work but i replaced 'main_line' to "self.main_line" everywhere and it's work! Tysm!!

Comment: My pleasure, feel free to edit the answer and mark your question as answered.